# How do I get the parent key more than one level up in Firebase Cloud Function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase cloud function using Node.js which triggers on create of a new record.

`exports.offerApproved = functions.database.ref('/stores/{storeName}/approved/{pushID}').onCreate((snapshot, event) => {})`

I am looking to find the `storeName` of the new records location. I have tried using the parent function but not sure how to move up more than one parent level.

Comment: I know any valid reference had a `.path` property. `console.log(snapshot)` and look for a path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to your onCreate function is a context, not an event:

```
exports.offerApproved = functions.database.ref('/stores/{storeName}/approved/{pushID}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {})
```

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path), you can use the params property on the context to access the wildcard values from the matched path:

```
context.params.storeName
context.params.pushID
```